# How to access props within a component?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to access `myVar` value within `handleClick`? Still struggling to get the basics right :-).  Tried passing it within `{myVar}` but still the same.

```
var Button = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
      return {counter: 1}
    },
    handleClick(){
      console.log(this.props.myVar); //getting undefined here
    },
    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} myVar="blah">{this.state.counter}</button>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to send myVar value from the parent component

Comment: Props are imported on instantiation of the component.

`ReactDom.render({
    <Button myVar={'blah'} />,
    document.getElementById('element-name')
});`

Answer (score 3):

Props are available everywhere on your Component which means that there is no need for you to pass it as a prop to the `button` tag. Just a correctly bound function will take care of that for you and since you're using `.createClass()` your functions are automatically bound to the instance of your component meaning that
the `handleClick` function already has access to both `this.props` and `this.state`.

```
handleClick: function (event) {
   console.log(this.props.myVar); //blah
}
```

But if you want to pass an extra variable to your function `handleClick` you need to pass a new function to your onClick handler. Remember to bind `this` so you have access to your instance as well

```
handleClick: function (event, myVar) {
   console.log(myVar);
}

<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, myVar)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

A property is bound to the component itself, so this.props will always point to the properties added via the parent, and not each part of markup like angular directives. To bind a variable to the onclick, you can do it like this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick("blah")}>{this.state.counter}</button>

Then youre handleclick will fetch it as its first parameter.
```

You can of course create your own button-component, and then pass in props like you do. Then the button-component will contain this.props.myVar

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the variable and access as a parameter in handleClick function  :

```
 var Button = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
  return {counter: 1}
},
handleClick(myVar){
  console.log(myVar) //consoles blabh; 
},
render(){
   let myVar="blabh";
    return(
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(myVar)} >{this.state.counter}    </button>
       );
    }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that events are not bound to your component by default, so to fix that just bind the the handler to this.

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} myVar="blah">{this.state.counter}</button>
```